# pivoting the results of unioned temporary tables

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have union 6 select statements, 3 of which are display total car sales in US, IN and UK which are then places in a temporary table. The other 3 statements display total boat sales in US, IN and UK which are also please in a temporary table.

These temp tables are then accessed through another select statement

the information is displayed by rows for each country, with the cars and boats as columns.

I know how to pivot a single select statement. my question is can the results from this pivoted, and if so where should I include the pivot operator

Comment: I replaced the incompatible database tags with "sql", but your question doesn't really make sense without sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't have the code but I can supply something with a similar scenario. thanks

Comment: Hi Mr Linoff please see code below

Comment: i am trying to type in the code but it is saying it is to long. can i email this to u?

Answer (score 0):

Put 6 union select into a CTE and do pivot. You also need to supply the data for pivot ( such as amount or date), so we may construct the structure for you pivot

Comment: it advises the code is to long , may i email this to you?

Comment: If you know how to use pivot in sql, there is no difference between a single select statement and 6 unions select inside CTE. I guess you can handle it by yourself

Comment: I am attempting to unsuccessfully.

Comment: `with pivotdata as 
(select categoryname, s.shipcountry, sum(od.unitprice * od.qty)
 as totalseafoodsales from sales.orders as s

inner join sales.orderdetails as od on s.orderid = od.orderid 
inner join production.products as p on p.productid = od.productid
inner join production.categories as pc on pc.categoryid = p.categoryid
where s.shipcountry = 'France' and pc.categoryname = 'seafood'
group by  categoryname, s.shipcountry
)

select totalseafoodsales, [Brazil], [USA], [France]
from pivotdata
pivot(sum( totalseafoodsales) for shipcountry in ([Brazil], [USA], [France])) as p;`